# Matrix does not update

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Whenever I'm assigning a new Matrix to myMatrix, the reference of myMatrix does not change. And as a result, there is no recomposition.

Anyone any idea on how to assign a new reference to myMatrix, or perhaps solve this in a different way?

```
@Composable
fun MatrixTest(){
    var myMatrix by remember { mutableStateOf(Matrix()) }

    Box(
        Modifier
            .graphicsLayer {
                translationX = myMatrix.values[Matrix.TranslateX]
                translationY = myMatrix.values[Matrix.TranslateY]
            }
            .border(2.dp, Color.Black)
            .size(100.dp)
            .pointerInput(Unit, myMatrix) {
                detectTransformGestures { centroid, pan, zoom, rotation ->
                    myMatrix.translate(pan.x, pan.y)

                    myMatrix = Matrix(myMatrix.values)
                }
            }
    )
}
```

Comment: Hey @user3872620, there's something I don't quite understand in your question. In your code I can see that you're assigning a new Matrix object to myMatrix when you do `myMatrix = Matrix(myMatrix.values)`, that should "assign a new reference to myMatrix", correct? I'm trying to understand why this would not trigger a recomposition since a new object is being assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Using a different equality policy for `mutableStateOf` is a solution. In this case, I used the `neverEqualPolicy` which considers any setting of the value as a change.

Reference:

```
/**
 * A policy never treat values of a [MutableState] as equivalent.
 *
 * Setting [MutableState.value] will always be considered a change. When applying a
 * [MutableSnapshot] that changes the state will always conflict with other snapshots that change
 * the same state.
 */
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <T> neverEqualPolicy(): SnapshotMutationPolicy<T> =
    NeverEqualPolicy as SnapshotMutationPolicy<T>
```

Code:

```
@Composable
fun TestMatrix(){
    var myMatrix by remember { mutableStateOf(Matrix(), neverEqualPolicy()) }

    Box(
        Modifier
            .graphicsLayer {
                translationX = myMatrix.values[Matrix.TranslateX]
                translationY = myMatrix.values[Matrix.TranslateY]
            }
            .border(2.dp, Color.Black)
            .size(100.dp)
            .pointerInput(Unit, myMatrix) {
                detectTransformGestures { centroid, pan, zoom, rotation ->
                    myMatrix.translate(pan.x, pan.y)

                    myMatrix = Matrix(myMatrix.values)
                }
            }
    )
}
```